# How does the event loop unblock itself from network I/O?

Tags: events, libuv

libuv has a central event loop and allows asynchronous network I/O, timers etc around it.

The high level architecutre as presented in the docs is:

[image]

When the event loop blocks for "ready" sockets (using epoll etc), how does it unblock itself if  none of the sockets are ready? It might miss some timers which could run out in the meantime.

If it immediately unblocks if none of the sockets are empty, and there are no timers to trigger, doesn't the event loop degenerate to "busy waiting" for sockets to get ready?

Answer (score 0):

`uv_run` makes sure to not busy wait by passing an additional timeout parameter to the polling function. On windows the implementation to calculate the timeout for the polling call basically looks like this

```
int uv__next_timeout(const uv_loop_t* loop) {
  const struct heap_node* heap_node;
  const uv_timer_t* handle;
  uint64_t diff;

  /* If not timer block indefinitely */
  heap_node = heap_min(timer_heap(loop));
  if (heap_node == NULL)
    return -1;

  /* Timer should have fired already */
  handle = container_of(heap_node, uv_timer_t, heap_node);
  if (handle->timeout <= loop->time)
    return 0;

  /* Timer fires in the future, compute the timeout until the 
     next timer should fire */
  diff = handle->timeout - loop->time;
  if (diff > INT_MAX)
    diff = INT_MAX;

  return (int) diff;
}
```

Only if no timers are available the loop will block until a socket / IO completion port is ready to be consumed, otherwise it will block for at most the time until the next timeout should fire. The `heap_min` makes sure to always return the next timer to not miss any.